# Receiving Error on TFRecordCompressionType.GZIP in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I get an error below when I run the code below. I have Tensorflow 2.0 installed

`test = tf.io.TFRecordOptions(tf.io.TFRecordCompressionType.GZIP)`

Error received

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.io' has no attribute 'TFRecordCompressionType'`

Answer (score 2):

`test = tf.io.TFRecordOptions(compression_type = 'GZIP')`